# Updating web service client in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, wsdl, axis

I have Axis web service and a client for it, both projects in Eclipse. I need to update my client (and also a wsdl file) when I make changes in web service (f.e., add new web method or change parameters of existing methods). How can it be done in Eclipse? Can it be done automatically?

Answer (score 2):

just create a new webservice client and it will update the old one

Comment: is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I've looked for a cleaner way but didn't find anything. Just creating it again.